# Java Spring Boot infinite redirect

Tags: java, spring, redirect

I'm using Spring Boot, I'm trying to make when user's going to any page `/web/**` he will redirecting to `/web/index.html`

So I have some code for this, but it works not correctly

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurerAdapter forwardToIndex(){
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry){
            registry.addViewController("/web/**").setViewName("redirect:/web/index.html");
        }
    };
}
```

It's an infinite redirect to `index.html`, but it should be only once.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use redirect. `registry.addViewController("/web/**").setViewName("/web/index");` is enough.  Just make sure that `web/index.html` does really exists under your `resource/static` or `resource/templates`.